# Parking south of Chicago near CTA to central Chicago

Tags: usa, public-transport, automobiles, chicago

I'm coming to Chicago from the southeast on I-94 this weekend. Is there a place to leave my car for the weekend, somewhere close to a public transportation depot? I'm considering leaving behind the car and using public transportation until I go back home. If there is such a place, what will it cost on the weekend?

Comment: Park it in South Bend and take a train

Comment: If you're coming via I-94 where are you starting from?

Comment: From the shining city of Ann Arbor. South bend pretty far from Chicago, but it is en route and the train rates aren't bad at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically your best bet would be to use the [Northern Indiana Commuter Transportation District's](http://www.nictd.com/) South Shore line to take a train to Chicago.

Personally having driven on both I-94 and I-90 South East Chicago, Gary, and Hammond might not be the best places one might leave a car, so I would suggest going to South Bend as it might be a little out of the way, though not much and you can catch a train from there to Chicago's Union Station.

You can check the schedules [online](http://www.nictd.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Many options. Here is one - I live right by it.  Parking garage on Maxwell and Halsted. It's about 8/day. Limit technically 72 hours but never had a problem. CTA blue line short bus (#8 Halsted north), cab, or 12 minute walk. CTA stop is UIC-Halsted, will get you anywhere you need to go.

Ps - Maxwell and Halsted is directly off 90/94/55/290 so basically every expressway.

Comment: Any changes with this? I'd like to try this in a week or so.

Comment: I haven’t checked the rates in a while but I don’t know of a better option

Comment: But still open?

Comment: Yea most definitely. My car is there right now